# Adjust dates in R

Tags: r

Could you tell me why the dates are coming off weird? I will insert an executable code below. You may notice that date1 and date2 have the wrong dates.

The link to download the database df: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pi2cQk1Dl1UAH_vj1vY73fHNX3RLDRj2/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102073768617937039119&rtpof=true&sd=true

```
df<-read_excel('C:/Users/Jose/Desktop/df.xlsx')

df<-subset(df,df$date2<df$date1) 

dim_data<-dim(df)

day<-c(seq.Date(from = as.Date(df$date2[1]),
                to = as.Date(df$date2[dim_data[1]]),
                by = "1 day"))

df_grouped<-matrix(nrow = 9,ncol=6)
colnames(df_grouped)<-c("Id","date1","date2","Week","D","DR01")


for (k in 1:9) {
  df_grouped[k,]<-c(subset(df,date2==day[k])$Id[1], 
                                  subset(df,date2==day[k])$date1[1],
                                  subset(df,date2==day[k])$date2[1], 
                                  subset(df,date2==day[k])$Week[1],
                                  subset(df,date2==day[k])$D[1],
                                  sum(subset(df,date2==day[k])$DR01))
}
> df_grouped
      Id  date1        date2        Week       D     DR01
 [1,] "1" "1626739200" "1617321600" "Friday"   NA    "21"
 [2,] "1" "1626739200" "1617408000" "Saturday" NA    "24"
 [3,] NA  NA           NA           NA         NA    "0" 
 [4,] NA  NA           NA           NA         NA    "0" 
 [5,] NA  NA           NA           NA         NA    "0" 
 [6,] NA  NA           NA           NA         NA    "0" 
 [7,] "1" "1626739200" "1617840000" "Thursday" "Hol" "21"
 [8,] "1" "1626739200" "1617926400" "Friday"   NA    "11"
 [9,] "1" "1626739200" "1618012800" "Saturday" NA    "14
```

Comment: You are converting to a single vector with `c` that coerces the date to its integer storage mode

Comment: Thanks Akrun! Can help me to resolve this?

Comment: Try the code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way of solution!

```
   df_grouped <- df %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with("date"), as.Date)) %>% 
   group_by(date2) %>% 
   summarise(Id = first(Id),
             date1 = first(date1),
             Week = first(Week),
             D = first(D),
             DR01 = sum(DR01)) %>% 
   select(Id,date1,date2,Week,D,DR01)

df_grouped
# A tibble: 6 x 6
     Id date1      date2      Week     D      DR01
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1     1 2021-07-20 2021-04-02 Friday   NA       21
2     1 2021-07-20 2021-04-03 Saturday NA       24
3     1 2021-07-20 2021-04-08 Thursday Hol      21
4     1 2021-07-20 2021-04-09 Friday   NA       11
5     1 2021-07-20 2021-04-10 Saturday NA       14
6     1 2021-07-20 2021-08-01 Thursday NA       13
 
df_grouped <- df_grouped %>% mutate(date1=format(date1,"%d/%m/%Y"),
                                    date2=format(date2,"%d/%m/%Y"))
 
df_grouped
# A tibble: 6 x 6
     Id date1      date2      Week     D      DR01
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1     1 20/07/2021 02/04/2021 Friday   NA       21
2     1 20/07/2021 03/04/2021 Saturday NA       24
3     1 20/07/2021 08/04/2021 Thursday Hol      21
4     1 20/07/2021 09/04/2021 Friday   NA       11
5     1 20/07/2021 10/04/2021 Saturday NA       14
6     1 20/07/2021 01/08/2021 Thursday NA       13
```